# Query to identify slow moving stock in SAP B1

Tags: sql, sapb1

I am trying to create a query that calculates the number of days since an item was last purchased based on the DocDate in the RDR1 table joined to the OITM table. The purpose of the query is to identify slow moving stock.

The query will be housed in excel and will then each product will have an excel formula placing it in an  ageing buckets to give a user clearer visibility.

[Excel snippet explaining end goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2Kts.png)

The initial code i uploaded I realised was incorrect as it was trying to do the aging calculation in the SQL code but I have realised I need to do that part in excel.
@Gordon Linoff supplied me with this code:

```
SELECT OITM.ItemCode, OITM.ItemName,
       DATEDIFF(day, MAX(RDR1.DocDate), GETDATE()) as days_since_last_order
FROM OITM 
     RDR1
     ON OITM.ItemCode = RDR1.ItemCode
WHERE OITM .OnHand > 0 
GROUP BY OITM.ItemCode, OITM.ItemName;
```

But I am getting the following error message:
[SQL error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBikE.png)

Help on this issue would be much appreciated and I hope that I have made what I am trying to do a lot clearer in this post. I am new to SQL so sorry in advance if the answer is obvious.

Thanks,
Callum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT OITM.ItemCode, OITM.ItemName,
       DATEDIFF(day, MAX(RDR1.DocDate), GETDATE()) as days_since_last_order
FROM OITM 
     JOIN RDR1
     ON OITM.ItemCode = RDR1.ItemCode
WHERE OITM .OnHand > 0 
GROUP BY OITM.ItemCode, OITM.ItemName;
```

Somehow, you lost the word JOIN

Comment: Thank you Neville. It works :) Thank you to Gordon if you see this as well, I appreciate both of you taking the time to help!